# Interval length inequality proof verification

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

If $\{(a_j,b_j]\}_{j=0}^{m}$ is a collection of intervals (not necessarily pairwise disjoint),and $(a,b] \subset  \bigcup_{j=0}^{m} (a_j,b_j]$, then $$l((a,b]) \leq \sum_{j=0}^{m} l((a_j,b_j])$$

My attempt: let $S$ be the smallest subset of $U = \bigcup_{j=0}^m (a_j,b_j]$(itself being a union of intervals) satisfying $(a,b] \subset S$  , S is an interval, being the union of intervals sharing at least one point.

Since $(a,b] \subset S$ Therefore, $$ l((a,b]) \leq l(S)$$

We also know that the sum of the lengths of closed or open intervals are the same, so $$\mathrm {Sum} = \sum_{j=0}^{m} l((a_j,b_j)) = \sum_{j=0}^{m} l((a_j,b_j]) $$

Therefore,we can use the union of the open intervals,and use the following lemma:

"An open set is the union of pairwise disjoint open intervals"

Since our new union $U^{'}$ of intervals is an open set,we apply the lemma in the following way:

There exists a $S^* \in U^{'}$ where $S \subset S^*$ ,and $S^*$ is disjoint with all other intervals $S_j$(excluding $S^*$).

And $$\mathrm {Sum} = l(S^*) + \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} S_j$$

And finally:

$$l((a,b]) \leq l(S) \leq l(S^*) \leq \mathrm {Sum}$$

QED.

Comment: Your argument for $S$ being an interval is not valid.

Comment: In my knowledge,any union of intersecting intervals is itself an interval,no? Is that incorrect? If so, can you provide a counter example please? Thank you.

Comment: Each of your intervals intersecting $(a,b]$ does not imply that all those intervals have a point in common.

Comment: I see .Thank you, I have now adjusted my proof to account for that.

Comment: I don't understand what your $S$ is. Hint for a correct proof: Use the ordering of the real line.

Comment: Please see edit.